# XCode 4 Connection Inspector not refreshing after new IBOutlet in source code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, iboutlet

Whenever I add a new `IBOulet` / rename an existing one in my source code, the associated File Owner Connection Inspector in `.xib` file does not get refreshed anymore.

If I close and reopen the project new outlets appear, but as long as I keep it open there is no way to access them. It happens in every `.xib` file, and it's not a matter of proper custom class name - it is always associated `ViewController`.

This issue started happening since **Xcode 4.4.1** update - anybody experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: Thats a bummer! Let me check!

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your outlets as properties rather than using "IBOutlet" in instance variables. I was having a worse problem where Xcode never showed the outlets I added as ivars. I was updating a xib that used the ivar approach. It never said my outlets existed, even relaunching Xcode, and claimed all the existing outlets were missing from the header ("your class" does not have an outlet "foo").

Here's the property-style outlet (in an OS X project):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSButton *okButton;
```

Edited to add: The problems were in a framework project included as a dependency of an app project together in a workspace, and I still had inconsistent issues with @property-based outlets. When I closed the workspace and opened the framework project alone, the problems went away. It does still like the @property outlets better in the context of the workspace.